# how to get data out of JSON request

Tags: jquery, json, api

Sorry i'm new to this and dont have a clue how to do this correctly. 
i want to extract data from this:

```
{
  "list": [
    { "brewery":"Strangeways", "beer":"Albino Monkey" },
    { "brewery":"St. Bernardus", "beer":"Pater 6" }
]
}
```

and this is what i have come up with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('http://example.com/api/temp/66', function(data) {
            var brewery=[];
        brewery[0]=data.list[0].brewery[1];
        var newHTML = [];
        $.each(brewery, function(index, value) {
                newHTML.push('<span>' + value + '</span>');
        });
        $(".element").html(newHTML.join(""));
    });

});
```

Comment: What isn't working?  You didn't ask a question.

Comment: you want just "beer" ?

Comment: its not return anything

Comment: this is wrong syntax `brewery[0]=data.list[0].brewery[1];`

Comment: The call to the api isn't returning anything?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
var brewery = JSON.parse(data);
```

You can then navigate brewery like

```
brewery.list[0]
brewery.list[1]
```

and so on..

Comment: Why are you calling JSON.parse? The JSON has already been parsed.

Answer (score 0):

The array of breweries is in `data.list` not `data.list[0]`, also you need `value.brewery` in the each

```
    $.each(data.list, function(index, value) {
            newHTML.push('<span>' + value.brewery + '</span>');
            // or value.beer to get the beer string
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('http://example.com/api/temp/66', function(data) {
        $.each(data.list, function (index, value) {
            $(".element").append('<span>' + value.brewery + '</span>');
        });
    });
});
```